# Send additional data to SQL along with the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Simplified case:

```
Database table Cars
ID (int)
Name (varchar)
Model (varchar)
```

On this table there is a trigger on UPDATE that will insert something like 'Name of car with ID # has been changed' to another table

From the backend a simple query is run

```
UPDATE Cars SET Name='My First Car' WHERE ID = 1
```

What I would like to accomplish is to send an additional value alongside the query so I can alter the trigger to do something like this: 'Name of car with ID # has been changed by user with ID #'

I am using SQL SERVER 2017 (v14)

What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using SQL Server 2016 use [`SESSION_CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) otherwise use [`CONTEXT_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/context-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and store the user information before calling the update.

Then, either way, within the trigger extract the user information and use it for your logging information.

Comment: Looking into this now. Thanks.

Comment: I've been experimenting a bit and it seems to fit my needs. Just to make sure; if I exec this query _EXEC sp_set_session_context 'ID', '1';UPDATE Cars SET Name=@Name WHERE ID = 1_ the session_context will only be valid for that session/thread, thus not affecting any other queries that will be executed correct?

Comment: The word session (for me) is a bit unclear, as it could reference to the current connection or login or thread, but it seems to be the current request, which solves my issue perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The information available to a trigger is limited to information in the table that the trigger is on, or information which is available to the system in general.

Since the user is not in the original table, you need the data to be available to the system in general. There's quite a lot of data like this. For example, you can know the name of the database you're in, using the built in `db_name()` function.

There is some information the system can give you based on the connection properties. For example, the `orignal_login()` function will give you the name of the user who actually made the connection to the SQL Server.

If you have a table of `Users` somewhere, that has, say, `(UserName, UserId)`,and if the user names in that table match the *actual login names* of the sql server logins, then you could use the result of `original_login()` to join onto that table, pull out the username, and now you have the user id:

```
create trigger t on cars after update as begin
   set nocount on;

   insert  myloggingtable(Message, EntryDateTime)
   select  concat('car with id ', inserted.id, ' was updated by ', u.UserId), getdate()
   from    inserted i
   join    Users    u on u.UserName = original_login()
end
```

As mentioned in the comments, since your application is connecting as an application specific account, this of course won't help you. In which case you could try [context_info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Most of the time though, the app or web app has its own login to the database, so finding out a specific user isn't possible.

Comment: Agreed. And it would be somewhat strange to store the server logins in a separate table anyway, because what happens if there's someone in the table who does not have a valid login, or vice versa? Given transport credentials, I wouldn't bother with a separate Id, I'd just log the actual `original_login()` value - granted that still won't work if the application is using application credentials, not forwarding user credentials.

Comment: Thanks, but as Dale pointed out, there is no seperate connection to the database for each user.

Comment: Where were you imagining you might get the user Id value from? Like a parameter to the trigger or something?

Comment: Assuming that comment was meant for me; My preferred method would be to send the ID (or any other data) from the query. Something like 'update cars set name='x' where id = 1 option data='123';

Comment: You could try [context info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as long as the application knows who the user is and can set that property. I have updated my answer to cover that case.

Comment: Dale's answer using session_context is better given you are on SQL 2017